# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' in views.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i want to create a registration form but i m getting an attribute error while running the application

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm


def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')
def register(request):
    registered=False
    if request.method=="POST":
        user_form=UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_from.is_valid():
            user=user_form.save()
            user.setpassword(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']
            profile.save()

            registered=True

        else:
        print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form=UserForm()
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()
    return(request,'basic_app/registration.html',

          {'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form,
            'registered':registered})
```

## output

Internal Server Error: /basic_app/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shoaib Khan\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Shoaib Khan\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 93, in **call**
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Shoaib Khan\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response

```
if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
[24/Dec/2018 15:34:51] "GET /basic_app/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 61448

Comment: Which line is giving you this error? What do you really want to do with that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of this line:

```
return(request,'basic_app/registration.html',

      {'user_form':user_form,
        'profile_form':profile_form,
        'registered':registered})
```

You've actually created a tuple here. Notice the the parenthesis around the three things that you're returning?

This is how you render a template in django:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

So in your case this will work:

```
render(request,'basic_app/registration.html', {
                                         'user_form':user_form,
                                         'profile_form':profile_form,
                                         'registered':registered
                                      })
```

For more information on `render` check out its [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
return(request,'basic_app/registration.html',

          {'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form,
            'registered':registered})
```

to

```
return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',

          {'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form,
            'registered':registered})
```